# Regex to extract multiple groups and atore in dataframe column in python 3.9

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a dataframe from which I would like to extract some information through regex.

```
name
?|{Type 2 diabetes mellitus, susceptibility to}, 125853 (3)
{Type 2 diabetes mellitus}, 125854 (3)
17,20-lyase deficiency, isolated, 202110 (3)
17-alpha-hydroxylase/17,20-lyase deficiency, 202110 (3)
?Agammaglobulinemia 4, 613502 (3)
?[Dysalbuminemic hypertriiodothyroninemia], 615999 (3)
3p- syndrome (4)
3m-syndrome (4)
```

I would like extract the text and the digits after the comma. The final dataframe should be like this.

```
name                                            newColumn0                               newColumn1
?|{Type 2 diabetes mellitus, susceptibility to} Type 2 diabetes mellitus, susceptibility to   125853
{Type 2 diabetes mellitus}, 125854 (3)          Type 2 diabetes mellitus                      125854
17,20-lyase deficiency, isolated, 202110 (3)    17,20-lyase deficiency, isolated              202110
17-alpha-hydroxylase/17,20-lyase deficiency, 202110 (3) 17-alpha-hydroxylase/17,20-lyase deficiency   202110
?Agammaglobulinemia 4, 613502 (3)               Agammaglobulinemia 4                          613502
?[Dysalbuminemic hypertriiodothyroninemia], 615999 (3) Dysalbuminemic hypertriiodothyroninemia       615999
3p- syndrome (4)                                3p- syndrome   
3m-syndrome (4)                                 3m-syndrome
```

I am using following regular expression which only works for first 2 rows.

```
df_new = df.join(df[name].str.extractall("{(.*)}, (.*) \(")[0]
                                       .unstack()
                                       .add_prefix('newColumn'))
```

How can I modify it to include other patterns as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df[['newColumn0', 'newColumn1']] = df['name'].str.extract(r'\??\|?[[{]?(.*?)[]}]?(?:,\s+(\d+))?\s+\(\d+\)')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k22fN0/2).

Note that the regex contains two capturing groups, so `Series.str.extract` extracts two strings to fill the `newColumn0` and `newColumn1` columns.

*Details*:

- `\??` - an optional `?`
- `\|?` - an optional `|`
- `[[{]?` - an optional `[` or `{`
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than newline as few as possible
- `[]}]?` - an optional `]` or `}`
- `(?:,\s+(\d+))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `,` - a comma
  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits.
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Comment: I have added two more rows which are not captured with the current regex suggestion. Could you please tell how can it be modified. Thanks

Comment: @rshar but those do not follow the same pattern, what do you need to extract from the two lines?

Comment: My mistake. I added the rows in the output.